# Find the smallest value that can have $\measuredangle ACE$.

Tags: geometry

For reference: . For a regular polygon ABCDE...of n sides find the smallest value that
can have $\measuredangle ACE$.

My progress:

[image]

I closed the ABCDE polygon and calculated the sum of the Interior Angles.
$ n = 5 \rightarrow S=180(5-2) = 540^o$

$\measuredangle ACE < 180^o\\ \measuredangle B = \measuredangle C=\measuredangle D\\ \measuredangle EAB = \measuredangle AED$

but I can't see other relationships

Comment: Is it a regular polygon? Is it a polygon with 5 vertices (ABCDE) or it can be more linked to $n$?

Comment: answer in book: $36^o$

Comment: @AbdoulHaki..regular polygon..I have already corrected the statement, There are  n sides, not exactly 5 sides

Comment: For a *regular* polygon the angle is $\frac{n-4}{n} \pi$ which increases with $n$.

Comment: The smallest value would be for a pentagon ABCDE where the angle ACE would be $36^o$.  By increasing the sides we increase the ACE Angle.. I believe that's it

Comment: @dxiv..exactly, I think this is the idea for the resolution

Comment: @dxiv,,$\frac{n-4}{n} \pi $ Where does this relationship come from?

Comment: @petaarantes That's an inscribed angle that subtends $n-4$ out of the $n$ equal arcs.

Comment: @petaarantes If not by a circumscribed circle, you can calculate through isosceles triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDE$, with known apex angles $\angle B$ and $\angle D$, so you should be able to find angles $\angle ACB$ and $\angle DCE$, and hence $\angle ACE$.

Comment: @dxiv grateful for the explanation

Comment: @peterwhy grateful for the explanation